# multidimensional array, equivalent array object, vectors with key string

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I searched the internet but can not find anything related, I need to do the following,

Example illustration only:

```
int Main(){
    int i;
    string Key;
    myArray = Array(); //Blank
    char s[ 11 ] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!' };

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){//
        myArray.push("Key"+i, s[i]);//push(key,value) -- imaginary function
    }

    forEach(myArray as Key){// -- imaginary function
        cout << "Key: " << Key << " - Value: " << myArray[Key] << endl;
    }
}
```

I need that I can set ARRAY KEYS specific, because these keys are to control the data source without mixing information.

It need not be exactly like that, but what I need is something that the end result of me the same way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider using the map container please take a look @ this examples it is very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/CppStlMultiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)?

```
std::map<std::string, char> myMap;

// Add an element to the map with key = "key1" and value = 'a'
myMap["key1"] = 'a';

// Access the element with key = "key1"
cout << mymap["key1"];
```